# Dagger activity graph and separated modules

Tags: android, dependency-injection, android-volley, dagger

I have an Android application and I'm trying to use dagger. I decided to use a global graph + activity graphs. I have three modules:

AndroidModule

```
@Module(library = true)
public class AndroidModule {

  private final MApplication mApplication;

  public AndroidModule(MyApplication application) {
    mApplication = application;
  }

  @Provides @Singleton @ForApplication Context provideApplicationContext() {
    return mApplication;
  }
}
```

MyAppModules

```
@Module(
    injects = {
            MainActivity.class,
            AddFragment.class,
            AddMapFragment.class,
            MyActivity.class,
            ListFragment.class,
            MyMapFragment.class,
            RetainFragment.class,
            SingleActivity.class,
            UserActivity.class,
            UserLoginFragment.class,
            UserProfileActivity.class,
            UserProfileFragment.class,
            UserRegisterFragment.class,
            WelcomeFragment.class
    },
    complete = false,
    library = true,
    includes = ActivityModule.class
)
public class MyAppModule {

  private final Bus mBus = new Bus();

  @Provides @Singleton Bus provideBus() {
    return mBus;
  }

  @Provides @Singleton
  RequestQueue provideRequestQueue(@ForApplication Context context) {
    return Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
  }

  @Provides @Singleton Api provideApi(RequestQueue queue) {
    return new AppApi(queue);
  }

  @Provides Logger provideLogger() {
    return new MyLogger();
  }
}
```

ActivityModule

```
@Module(
    complete = false,
    library = true
)
public class ActivityModule {

  private BaseActivity mActivity;
  public ActivityModule() {}

  public ActivityModule(BaseActivity activity) {
    mActivity = activity;
  }

  @Provides @Singleton @ForActivity Context provideActivityContext() {
    return mActivity;
  }

  @Provides @Singleton LocationClientFactory provideLocationClientFactory() {
    return new LocationClientFactory(mActivity);
  }
}
```

I had to use include on `MyAppModule` for the `ActivityModule`, without it, the application crashed saying it could find a constructor on `Context` and couldn't inject the `Activity`'s `Context`.

Is the graph configured correctly? I'm adding the modules to the graph in the `Application` and in a `BaseActivity` and I thought it was enough and I didn't need the include, but I'm not sure I completly understand the configuration process of this.

**Edit**

Like this, dagger gives no errors but if I try to inject an `Activity` `Context`, at runtime it's `null`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution, if anyone is interested, was to remove

```
injects = {
        MainActivity.class,
        AddFragment.class,
        AddMapFragment.class,
        MyActivity.class,
        ListFragment.class,
        MyMapFragment.class,
        RetainFragment.class,
        SingleActivity.class,
        UserActivity.class,
        UserLoginFragment.class,
        UserProfileActivity.class,
        UserProfileFragment.class,
        UserRegisterFragment.class,
        WelcomeFragment.class
}
```

from MyAppModule and put it in ActivityModule.

Comment: That's because (if you are using the [Activity Graphs](https://github.com/square/dagger/tree/master/examples/android-activity-graphs) sample) your activity object graph is the thing that `addsTo` the MyAppModule. Also, if you are doing `include` of your activity module I'm pretty sure that part of the graph is constructed before you want it to be, which is when the Activity is alive only.

Comment: So check it as an answer

Comment: Hey @alex, can you please put here how exactly did you create the graphs in the Application And Activity classes?